# Can´t connect Visual Studio with Github

Tags: visual-studio, github, authorization

Good morning,

I am trying to connect my Visual Studio with my Github account.
But for me some strange behaviour is happening.

I click on the plus and then Github.

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OedBY.png)

After that I am in my Browser where I must log in, which I do and accept the authorization. After that the Microsoft-Website says everything went well and that I can go back to VS.

But in VS nothing happened.

When I go into my Github account into the setting, Applications, Authorized OAuth Apps Visual Studio is listed. But still nothing in VS itself
[image]

Does anyone know what I have to do, or did I make a mistake?

Comment: You are trying to connect to your git account from your vscode? Did I understand your question correctly? or is it Vice-versa?

Comment: yeah, Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest VSCode. Install gitlens extension to manage GIT from vscode. You will see an icon (accounts) at the sidebar like the one below (above  the settings icon)

[image: vscode_accounts]

If you tap on it, it will ask you to log in with your GitHub account.

OR

Check whether "git" is enabled in your vscode settings.
To check that,

1. Files>preferences>settings
2. Type "git: enabled" in the search bar

There will be an option "git", it needs to be enabled if it's not already.

Please find the attached screenshot

[image: vscode_settings]

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i am not using VS Code, i code in Visual Studio 2019.